# DRF - Prevent users from referencing objects that do not belong to them

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models like so with a parent child relation:

**models.py**

```py
class Bank(...):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', ...)

class Account(...)
    bank = models.ForeignKey('Bank', ...)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', ...)
```

I am using DRF and want to provide API access to these models. I want to ensure that `Users` can only access their own data. On the viewsets I can retrict the querysets to just the objects the user "owns" like so:

**views.py**

```py
class BankViewSet(...):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(
            user = request.user
        )
```

And I can do the same for `Accounts`.

However, how can I stop a user from creating an `Account` via POST request with a `Bank` that they do not own? I want to ensure that users can only create `Accounts` that belong to a `Bank` that they own.

How can I enforce/check that the `Bank` in the `Account` POST request contains the same user as the requestor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) on the `AccountSerializer` class, as

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            "bank",
            "field_1",
            "field_2"
        )

    def validate_bank(self, bank_instance: Bank):
        if bank_instance.user == self.context["request"].user:
            return bank_instance
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Not belongs to you!!!")
```